# Are single complements the same as seperate complements?

Tags: logic

Is **(A' +  B')** the same as **(A + B)'** ?

*Note: The apostrophe ( ' ) represents the complement*

Comment: They are not equivalent. The intersection of A and B is a subset of the first expression, but it is not a subset of the second set.

Comment: Check out the rules of Augustus [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which are valid for both logic, computer algebra and set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As a counterexample pick $A=0$ and $B =1$. Then:
$$
A' + B' = 0' + 1' = 1 + 0 = 1 \neq 0 = 1' = (0 + 1)' = (A+B)'.
$$